# how to convert string into single dimension array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, string

Please help me to convert a string into single dimension array...

example

```
$str = abc,xyz,pqr;
```

convert to

```
$arr = array('abc','xyz','pqr');
```

Comment: can anyone help me to convert this...???

Answer (score 3):

Try with `explode` like

```
$str = 'abc,xyz,pqr';
$str_arr = explode(',',$str);
print_r($str_arr);
```

Try this [**EXPLODE**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 1):

use php function

```
explode(',',$str);
```

Comment: hi gautam i know explode function it gives output as array( 0 =>'abc', 1 => 'xyz', 2 => 'pqr'). this is not i want I want this array('abc','xyz','pqr')

Comment: that's how you instantiate your array and by default an array should have keys